# Trying to run my server.js with node command prompt throws a connection refused error

Tags: html, ajax, node.js

When I try to run in node.js command prompt

```
node server.js
```

it refuses the connection, tried with curl and same. My server.js:

```
  var express     = require('express');
    var app         = express();
    var mongoose     = require('mongoose');

    // Conexión con la base de datos
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/angular-todo');

    // Configuración
    app.configure(function() {
        // Localización de los ficheros estÃ¡ticos
        app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
        // Muestra un log de todos los request en la consola        
        app.use(express.logger('dev'));
        // Permite cambiar el HTML con el método POST                   
        app.use(express.bodyParser());
        // Simula DELETE y PUT                      
        app.use(express.methodOverride());
    });

    // Definición de modelos
    var Todo = mongoose.model('Todo', {
        text: String
    });

    // Rutas de nuestro API
    // GET de todos los TODOs
    app.get('/api/todos', function(req, res) {
        Todo.find(function(err, todos) {
            if(err) {
                res.send(err);
            }
            res.json(todos);
        });
    });

    // POST que crea un TODO y devuelve todos tras la creación
    app.post('/api/todos', function(req, res) {
        Todo.create({
            text: req.body.text,
            done: false
        }, function(err, todo){
            if(err) {
                res.send(err);
            }

            Todo.find(function(err, todos) {
                if(err){
                    res.send(err);
                }
                res.json(todos);
            });
        });
    });

    // DELETE un TODO específico y devuelve todos tras borrarlo.
    app.delete('/api/todos/:todo', function(req, res) {
        Todo.remove({
            _id: req.params.todo
        }, function(err, todo) {
            if(err){
                res.send(err);
            }

            Todo.find(function(err, todos) {
                if(err){
                    res.send(err);
                }
                res.json(todos);
            });

        })
    });

// Carga una vista HTML simple donde irá nuestra Single App Page
// Angular Manejará el Frontend
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./public/index.html');
});

// Escucha en el puerto 8080 y corre el server
app.listen(8080, function() {
    console.log('App listening on port 8080');
});
```

Port 8080 is open so no java service running nor wamp/xampp. No idea what is the problem since yesterday this was running without problems.

The error:

```
C:\Users\Pablo\Desktop\TODOLIST>node server.js
express deprecated app.configure: Check app.get('env') in an if statement server
.js:11:5
connect deprecated multipart: use parser (multiparty, busboy, formidable) npm mo
dule instead node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\bodyParser
.js:56:20
connect deprecated limit: Restrict request size at location of read node_modules
\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\multipart.js:86:15
connect deprecated methodOverride: use method-override npm module instead server
.js:19:21
App listening on port 8080

C:\Users\Pablo\Desktop\TODOLIST\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\s
erver.js:228
        process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                            ^
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1010:19)
```

Comment: "refuses the connection" sounds more like you can't connect to your mongo database rather than failure to bind to port 8080

Comment: Have you tried `sudo node server.js`?

Comment: I'm on windows. And yes, I'm running as admin

Comment: @tier1 is correct, the error is being thrown by the MongoDB driver so it can't connect to the MongoDB server for some reason.

Comment: @robertklep now we have to guess why happens that :P

Comment: @Pablo the obvious question would be: _"are you sure that there is a MongoDB server running on localhost:27017?"_

Comment: @robertklep yes it is, I'm using robomongo if that helps

Comment: This really sounds like mongo isn't running. You should try to minimize the source code until it stops failing. Then try to make the minimal-fail case running. I predict, that it will fail as long as they mongoose.connect statement is there. If that's the case: check your firewall, try 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost, re-install mongoose and mongo, disable your antivirus.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try taking out the port number so that the line in the app.js looks like:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/angular-todo');
```

It worked for me!